# How to create posts or pages with the names in wordpress?

Tags: permalinks, multi-language, slug, plugin-wpml

When you develop a site on wordpress you may want to create posts/pages with the same name, something that wordpress does not allow by default.

Use cases:

```
 example.com/en/contact
 example.com/fr/contact
 example.com/en/support/contact
```

I am currently using [WPML](http://wpml.org/) plugin in order to create multilanguage sites and I encountered this limitation in wordpress.

How can I solve this problem? Do you know any tricks or plugins that would allow me to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you develop a site on wordpress you may want to create posts/pages with the same name, something that wordpress does not allow by default.

This is statement is not true. WordPress will allow you to set up pages with the "directory" structure that you specified right out of the box. I was just able to do this on my test installation. I created a page with slug "en" and then created a child page named "taco". Next I created a page named "fr" and added a child to this page named "taco". Both taco pages have the slug of "taco". There may be an issue with the plugin that you are using. Have you tried this without the plugin installed?

Comment: Thanks, you are right - I notified WPML about this, let see what they will reply http://forum.wpml.org/topic.php?id=3506&replies=3#post-15552

Comment: It looks that this is a design issue with the WPML plugin because the translated pages are considered to share the same parent. This may seam logical but when combined with the `slug` verification it will prevent you from using the same slug on translations. I hope that WPML is going to find a solution for this because otherwise it will make sense to create root pages for each language and use just WordPress instead of the plugin.

Comment: No crap! I'm looking at the same thing with WPML and had no clue this was actually possible in core WP!